# CakePHP Paginatorgroup by / order by

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

Query:

```
SELECT  * from Entlehnungen 
WHERE status = 'retour' 
GROUP BY proben_id 
ORDER BY proben_id DESC, id DESC
```

In cake I create following code

```
unset($this->request->params['named']['sort']);
$this->Paginator->settings['Entlehnungen'] = array(
        'limit' => 500,
        'order' => array('Entlehnungen.proben_id' => 'DESC',
                         'Entlehnungen.id' => 'DESC'),
        'group' => array('Entlehnungen.proben_id')
);
$entlehnungens = $this->paginate(null, $conditions);
```

The problem is, that it looks like that the `order by` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is here:

`GROUP BY proben_id 
ORDER BY proben_id DESC, id DESC`

if you group by one field, that means that most fields will be randomly chosen.

so if you have data like

```
proben_id : id 
1    :    1
2    :    2
1    :    3 
2    :    4
```

the result for your query is:

```
proben_id : id 
1    :    1
2    :    2
```

so you can't order by `id`,

so if you have just one grouping field then

`ORDER BY proben_id DESC, id DESC`  **equal**  `ORDER BY proben_id DESC`

because there is nothing to order after `proben_id` - you have just 1 row per unique `proben_id`

To get your second level ordering you need include `id` field as grouping field:

`GROUP BY proben_id, id 
ORDER BY proben_id DESC, id DESC`

And php code  should be like:

```
$this->Paginator->settings['Entlehnungen'] = array(
        'limit' => 500,
        'group' => array('Entlehnungen.proben_id','Entlehnungen.id'),
        'order' => array('Entlehnungen.proben_id' => 'DESC',
                         'Entlehnungen.id' => 'DESC')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'order' => array('Entlehnungen.proben_id DESC','Entlehnungen.idDESC'),
```